# Broadcast data using actioncable on specific datetime

Tags: javascript, ruby, actioncable, real-time-updates, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using the rails 6 for my project and I want to know How can I broadcast date on specific datetime using the **actioncable** in rails.For example I have a campaign which start on 30/07/2020. On that date I want show specific data on the view in **realtime**. I don`t want user will need to refresh the page and see the data. Let me know way to implement this using actioncable.

Comment: Use sidekiq scheduler and active job

Comment: Why the Javascript tag? Irrelevant tags can waste member's time.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Added Javascript tag because solution maybe possible through javascript.

Comment: @bravemaster Thanks. But I can`t use sidekiq and active job. Its not too reliable for my scenario.

Comment: You only mention Rails in your question. If you would welcome a Javascript solution you need to say so in the question. That cannot be inferred from the tag.